# How to request object.id in form clean data funtion

Tags: django, forms, object, django-forms, request

Have a models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    variation_1 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    variation_2 = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    variation_3 = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='buyer')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    variations_select = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=VARIATIONS)
```

**in forms.py**

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    variations_select = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VARIATIONS)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = [
            'variations_select'
        ]
```

i need to create a clean function that will check if `variation_1` or `variation_2` or `variation_3` are availiable in `Product`. For this a need request `Product.id` to  `def clean_variations_select(self):` How to do this?

```
def clean_variations_select(self):
    product = Product.object.get(id = product.id)
    variations_select = self.cleaned_data.get("variations_select")
        if variations_select == "Variation_1" and product.variation_1 == False:
                raise forms.ValidationError("variation_1 was sold already")
        else:
                return variations_select
```

`product = Product.object.get(id = product.id)` - don't work cause Order isn't created to database yet(but in rendering view link to new order creation i have that ../product.id/new_order).

Comment: Can you post your `urls.py`?

Comment: Your `product` model field in class `Order` does not have a foreign key relationship to class `Product` but instead to `WowRaid`? Is that how it's supposed to be for your design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an `__init__` method for your class which should accept your product id as an argument.

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.product_id = kwargs.pop('product_id')
    super(OrderForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
```

When you initialize your form, you pass your `product_id` as a keyword argument.

```
 OrderForm(request.POST, product_id=product_id)
```

And in clean method you can use `self.product_id` to get the `Product` object you want.

```
def clean_variations_select(self):
    product = Product.object.get(id=self.product_id)
    variations_select = self.cleaned_data.get("variations_select")
    if variations_select == "Variation_1" and product.variation_1 == False:
        raise forms.ValidationError("variation_1 was sold already")
    else:
        return variations_select
```